# Why is the Arale from Dr. Slump in Dragon Ball so strong?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball

Norimaki Arale is a character from the anime *Dr. Slump* who also appears in *Dragon Ball*. In *Dragon Ball*, she's insanely strong. It seems that no one can beat her. Why is she so strong?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

According to Vegeta in the anime series, it's because she's a gag comic character the reason she has absurd strength.

[Vegeta vs Arale](https://universal-dragon-ball.fandom.com/wiki/Vegeta_vs._Arale_Norimaki)

In the original Dr Slump, she also was insanely strong, she broke the Earth in 2 by accident once with a punch.

Answer (score 0):

She is what people believe Saitama is. She's an actual gag character from a gag manga, Dr. Slump. She's basically the Bugs Bunny of Dragon Ball. Her powers include Plot Manipulation and such, where she can become the author herself and replace Tori-Bot, Toriyama's own avatar in the anime. Which means she can exist on a higher dimension of existence that most other characters without fourth-wall awareness can't even sense.